# Jax-RS HeaderParam automatic conversion

Tags: jax-rs

In reading the Jax-RS spec it's not clear to me how a @HeaderParam automatic conversion for the Java primitive boolean would be handled in the event the incoming string can not be converted to "true" or "false".  e.g. if a value of "xxx" is passed would a Bad Request exception be thrown ?

The Jax-RS implementation I'm working with seems to never throw an exception but rather converts an "xxx" string to boolean value of false.

Comment: If it's not in the spec, it's probably something that is implementation specific. The fact the your implementation makes non-true values false, doesn't seem too off to me as far as correctness. I mean anything that is not true is false, right? I've seen this type of behavior in other frameworks also, so it doesn't surprise me. Generally Bad Request (or non-handled exceptions in general) are cause by non-fixable problems. This issue can easily be fixed just be making non-true values false.